# Is there a relationship between variance in a dependent variable and R2?

Tags: regression, variance, r-squared

I know this is a tricky question because it will depend on the exact relationship. But, generally speaking, do models tend to have a larger or smaller R2 if there is high variance in the dependent variable?

I can imagine this both ways. Larger variance would mean more variance to explain, so larger R2? Or, larger variance means the dependent variable is less predictable so lower R2?

Comment: What does the dependent variables variation have to do with the variance explained by the model? Your rationale makes no sense.  The available data could cover a wide range of values for the dependent variable giving it a wide variation but the relationship can be strongly linear and vice versa. R$*2$ dependence on the size of the residuals and not on the design of the data.

Comment: @Michael chermick .This question is fallacious.Your comment is valid.

Answer (score 1):

One way to calculate R-squared (R2) is:

R2 = 1.0 - (absolute_error_variance / dependent_variable_variance)

which makes the variance relationship explicit and easier to reason about.

Comment: Okay so the point is the ratio of  of variance do to error/ total variance is what determines R$^2$ and not the total variance. so if the error term variance is doubled and so is the total variance the R$^2$ does not change.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Two questions... 1) Are there different ways of calculating R2 that would not have this property? 2) Am I right that this suggests that as variance in the dependent variable goes up, so does R2?

Comment: R2 can be interpreted as telling you how much of the variance in the dependent data is explained by a given model. If a different data set with increased variance in the dependent data is used with the same model, of course the R2 can change for that new situation - for example, the increased dependent data variance may be due to an increase in noise.